# How to fetch key-value from array of hashes in perl

Tags: perl, hash

My code:

```
my @emp_details = [
    {
        CID => '21',
        ID => '1',
        ORDERING => '1',
        PID => '143'
    },
    {
        CID => '22',
        ID => '2',
        ORDERING => '1',
        PID => '67'
    }
];
```

Expected output: Values of all the key - ID, i.e.:
`[1,2]`

i.e. Need to fetch both the hashes in `the emp_details` list and get the value from each ID.

How to do in perl?

My trials:

```
my %hash =
map {$_->{ID} } @departments;
```

errors out: `Not a HASH reference`

I tried with `map {$_->{ID} } %departments;`

There was no response in this case as well.

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`.

Comment: Yes, have these already in my code.

Comment: I say this because using strict would cause clear errors when using a variable that hasn't been declared, like `%departments`.

Answer (score 5):

Do you really have `my @emp_details = [ ... ];`? `[]` constructs an array and returns a reference to it, meaning `@emp_details` would get populated with a single element (a reference to an array).

I'm going to assume you have the following instead:

```
my @emp_details = (
    {
        CID => '21',
        ID => '1',
        ORDERING => '1',
        PID => '143'
    },
    {
        CID => '22',
        ID => '2',
        ORDERING => '1',
        PID => '67'
    }
);
```

Well, the first problem with your attempt is that the array is named `@emp_details`, not `@departments`.

The second problem with your attempt is that you are assigning the list of ids to a hash, which doesn't make sense.

Fixed:

```
my @ids = map { $_->{ID} } @emp_details;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are constructing the array of hashes incorrectly. `[]` is a constructor for an anonymous arrayref, which is a scalar, but you are putting it in an array, resulting in an array with one value: a reference to another array. Simply use `()` (the parentheses don't create a structure, but they are necessary for precedence over the assignment operator).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @emp_details = (
    {
        CID => '21',
        ID => '1',
        ORDERING => '1',
        PID => '143'
    },
    {
        CID => '22',
        ID => '2',
        ORDERING => '1',
        PID => '67'
    }
);
my @ids = map { $_->{ID} } @emp_details;
```